# I get fringes when I use gradient brush for the background

Tags: windows-phone-7, lineargradientbrush

I am using a gradient brush for the phone page background but i am not getting a smooth gradient but instead get color fringes in the background. The fringes are about 16 pixel wide. I am simply using.

```
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF489048" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF489048" Offset="1" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFB7DBB7" Offset="0.5" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a slight change in your WMAppManifest.xml file, which can be found in the Properties folder.

Make sure you are setting the Bits per Pixel in the App tag, like this:

```
<App BitsPerPixel="32" ... >
```

Comment: This is a dangerous idea! You won't see your flawed design on emulator.

Comment: The setting is working, but there are a few side-effects: Phones with OLED-Screen cannot handle 32 bit colors and will ignore it. Also your app will perform somewhat slower (and what is one of the main reasons it's turned off by default). You should reconsider using a gradient and use an image instead for example.

Comment: Yes, the current hardware spec only specifies the requirement to support 16 bits per pixel.  However, this setting was specifically put in place with Mango to allow developers to take advantage of hardware support of 32 bpp.  There's nothing in the design guidelines that indicate that you should not use it.  If a lower-capability phone is used, it will still be supported, just with banding.  Make your app look crappy across all platforms, or nice on most-- what's your choice?

Answer (score 1):

WP7 phones currently use 16 bit systems due to type of LCD screen. One pixes got: 5 bits are for red, 5 for blue, 6 for green (humans see a wider spectrum of green color). Only good solution to this problem is to... stop using gradients that cause "stripes", though, sometimes it may give good UX.